# angular *ngif element value in an a range of numbers

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm building a mean stack project and I was trying to show elements in a table only if their number in a predefined range of numbers.
I found a way to resolve the problem by using this :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
                    <tr *ngIf="(item.num > 4) && (item.num < 10)">
```

but I'm still wondering if there is a better way to do it
something like this (which didn't work):

```
*ngIf="item.num === [5,9]"
```

is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a pipe maybe, then your ngIf could be something like:

`*ngIf="item.num | between:5:9"`

```
@Pipe({name: 'between'})
export class BetweenPipeimplements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, start: number, end: number): boolean{
    return value > start && value < end;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your data using the regular array methods and save it to the property:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    public items!: { num: number }[];

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        // some test objects...
        const testData = [...Array(20).keys()].map(item => {
            return { num: item };
        });
        this.items = testData.filter(item => item.num > 4 && item.num < 10);
    }
}
```

And just get the items you need:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        <td>item #{{ item.num }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use other events (such as a button click) to update this collection.

**Note**: don't use functions in *ngFor data source (like `*ngFor="let item of loadItemsFromServer()`).
The change detection process will call it many times.